# Link to the chat has disappeared?

Tags: support, feature-request, chat

Is it only me or was the link to the chat removed from travel? Right now, the only way that I see is to scroll to the bottom, where the site-wide chat is listed, click on that, search for the travel chat and then go there. Should we not at least have it under "help"?

Comment: Perhaps it's a sign ;)

Answer (score 10):

Click on the "Stack Exchange" logo/link in the top left of the screen.

The SE sites you frequent will be listed at the top, with a chat button next to the current site. Click on that link, and you're in Chat.

Comment: Thanks for that. REALLY hard to find though. If we want more people in chat, I would recommend to make a more obvious link somewhere.

Comment: Not very user friendly on the part of developers but oh well...

Answer (score 5):

Click on “Stack Exchange” at the top left. There is a list of sites, starting with the current site and the meta site. Next to the main site, there is a link to chat.

If you're missing something else from the old top bar, see
[New top bar quick reference guide / Where has the link to  gone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210186/new-top-bar-quick-reference-guide-where-has-the-link-to-x-gone) on the main meta.